# Windows 10 - Powershell - PackageManagement - Install-Package - 'not a properly-formed module'

Tags: powershell, windows-10

Does anyone know how to fix this?

I am trying to install Firefox in Windows 10 using the new Install-Package cmdlet without success.

```
PS C:\_scripts> Find-Package Firefox

Name                           Version          Source           Summary
----                           -------          ------           -------
Firefox                        40.0.3           http://chocol... Bringing together all kinds of awesomeness to make browsing better for you


PS C:\_scripts> Find-Package Firefox | Install-Package
WARNING: The module 'Firefox' cannot be installed or updated because it is not a properly-formed module.
```

Comment: Try adding -verbose to the Install-Package cmd.  Might give a clue as to where the problem lies.

Comment: Can you install by adding the parameter `-RequiredVersion 37.0.1`?  Looks like there might have been a change to the package structure for later version of Chocolatey. The Chocolatey provider that ships with PowerShell V5 is a bit dated, has issues and is owned by the PowerShell team instead of the Chocolatey folks (who probably should be providing this provider).

Answer (score 1):

I found that I had an old config folder / file located @ 'C:\Chocolatey'

I deleted that, and then re-added Chocolatey as a PackageProvider without adding any package sources - see code below:

```
Get-Item 'C:\Chocolatey' | Remove-Item

Unregister-PackageSource chocolatey

Get-PackageProvider Chocolatey -ForceBootstrap

Find-Package vlc | Install-Package
```

Comment: The forcebootstrap should have recreated the C:\Chocolatey folder though, right?  Unfortunately the PowerShell provider does not use the new location where Chocolatey maintains config.

Comment: This seemed to solve it for me. I am not sure, but think it may have something to do with me adding the PackageSource last time. I should have mentioned I also removed that as well as the Chocolatey folder and used just the Get-PackageProvider command above.